# Retrive data from 2 tables with multiple conditions

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a question, So I have 2 tables :

**order:**

```
id   supplier_id    status
1    2              3
2    4              5
3    2              7
```

**gift_2_order:**

```
order_id  gift_id  order_price
1         2        4
2         1        5
3         2        6
1         6        1
2         4        9
```

So I want to get all orders, how many times is repeated in table : `gift_2_order` and the `total price`. For this example I want to get :

```
order    number_repetitions      total_price
1        2                        5
2        2                        14
3        1                        6
```

I tried :

```
SELECT
    ord.estimation_date,
    ord.order_date,
    ord.supplier_id,
    ord.status,
    count.(g2o.order_id),
    sum.(g2o.order_price)
FROM `order` ord
INNER JOIN gift_2_order g2o on ord.id = g2o.order_id
```

Can you help me please? Thank's in advance.

Comment: There's no `.` after `count` and `sum`. And there's only one `u` in `sum`.

Comment: And you need `GROUP BY ord.id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to group by `ord.id` and remove `.` from `count and sum`

```
         SELECT
                ord.id,
                count(g2o.order_id),
                sum(g2o.order_price)
            FROM `order` ord
            INNER JOIN gift_2_order g2o on ord.id = g2o.order_id
         group by ord.id order by ord.id
```

Comment: It's `ord.id`, not `ord.order_id`.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
    SELECT
    ord.order_id,
    count(g2o.order_id) as number_repetitions      ,
    sum(g2o.order_price) as total_price
    FROM `order` ord
    INNER JOIN gift_2_order g2o on ord.id = g2o.order_id
   group by ord.order_id
```

By the way "order" is no very good table name.

Comment: Why isn't 'order' a good table name? No reason that is isn't one.

Comment: because it is an SQL statement

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    t1.supplier_id,
    t1.status,
    count(t2.order_id) as total_orders,
    sum(t2.order_price) as total_amount
FROM `order` t1
join gift_2_order t2 where t1.id = t2.order_id group by t2.order_id
```

Comment: i think this will throw error. `ord.estimation_date` is not in group by clause

Comment: try it yourself before giving answer here. and search for `group by` clause. this query will still give error

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the need of doing a JOIN. Without a JOIN the query will be more performant...

This SQL fiddle will do the thrick for you:

```
SELECT
    order_id,
    count(order_id),
    sum(order_price)
FROM gift_2_order
GROUP BY order_id
ORDER BY order_id
```

If you do not need to join tables, don't do it.